# Using an SQL LIKE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to concatenate a variable into my LIKE clause. I believe I am doing it wrong. What can I do?

```
$query2= "SELECT user_id FROM interests WHERE interest LIKE     
'%'".$interest."'%'";
```

Answer (score 2):

The positioning of quotes are wrong. Check the single quotes around the % symbols.

`$query2= "SELECT user_id FROM interests WHERE interest LIKE '%".$interest."%'";`

What you had before was '%' $interest '%' instead of '% $interest %' which is what you'd want.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a correct way to concatenate a variable into a string:

```
$query2 = "SELECT user_id FROM interests WHERE interest LIKE '%" . $interest. "%'";
```

You had extra single quotes after `LIKE`.

However, you should used prepared statements using `mysqli_` or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

remove the single quotes after `%`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your extra quotes and don't forget to escape your external input (or use prepared statements).

```
$query2= "SELECT user_id FROM interests WHERE interest LIKE '%".
         mysqli_real_escape_string($interest)."%'";
```